# HangFire globalFilter Execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, background, hangfire

I'm running hangfire 1.7.11 on a Asp.net Project deployed in multiples appServices with a single database and I'm adding a global filter in the initial configuration :  `.UseFilter(new myFilter());` I'm adding some custom queues per appServices.

This filter is implementing `JobFilterAttribute, IElectStateFilter` and the method that I'm using is `OnStateElection`

As you see I have multiples server connecting to the same instance.

My question is when I use `BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => myMethod());` the filter that receive the stateElection will be the same where the `BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => myMethod());` or could be another one?

The problem is that i have a few method that needs to run where the process is started, so I have a validation in myFilter for the methods that need to run in a specific location, but in the else I'm no sure if the filter that recieve the method will be always where the `BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => myMethod());` has been called.